# How to set the provider in the connection string for OleDbConnection?

Tags: c#, find, connection, provider, oledbconnection

I am trying to create a connection to my database via `OleDbConnection`, but I do not know how to specify the provider.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OleDbConnection baglanti = new OleDbConnection();
baglanti.ConnectionString = @"Provider=.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server;Data Source=project.mdb";
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(komut, baglanti);
adapter.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874795/oledbconnection-connection-string

Comment: I already tried ı don't know my provider string how can I find it  I'm asking that

Comment: I rephrased the question to make it a bit clearer and shorter.

Comment: I recommend trying some tool that will build the connection string for you, such as LINQPad. It has a "wizard" of sorts - you specify the type of database, etc, and browse to its location, and it will do right by you. Of course, YMMV, but it works swell for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Sql Database, but it may work with an access database.

Import the .mdb file to your project, and then open it in your server explorer, when selected it will show you your connectionstring

[image]

Comment: wow - this is an eye test.  With your right hand covering your left eye, please read the last line....

Answer (score 0):

Create new Text Document and save it. Change the extension from .txt to .udl and then run it. On the provider tab select appropriate provider and click Next. After that, in the Data Source field, copy and paste the path to your database location followed by database name:

```
C:\..your path..\project.mdb
```

After that you can click Test Connection button and see if it connects. If test was successful, click OK.

At very the end, open .udl file with Notepad or simmilar and there you will have Connection string with provider and everything...

Hope this helps you.